# Where does Hybris store the Cronjob logs by default?

Tags: logging, cron, jobs, sap-commerce-cloud

I would like to know the process of the default Cron Job logging mechanism. As I see it is possible to download a log file for each job run as a zip, which contains the results and details of the actual run.

My questions: Where does Hybris store the *.log and *.zip files by default?

My reason for asking is that I would like to involve these log files in a centralized logging system with the standard tomcat logs as well, so that could be really helpful to be able to reach these files in the filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where does Hybris store the *.log and *.zip files by default?

Logs files store as media. CronJob has the one-to-many relationship with LogFile. Here LogFile extends Media.

**Declaration**

```
<collectiontype code="LogFileCollection" elementtype="LogFile" autocreate="true" generate="true"/>

<itemtype code="CronJob" jaloclass="de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.CronJob"
    extends="GenericItem" autocreate="true" generate="true">
    <deployment table="CronJobs" typecode="501" />
    <attributes>
        //.....

        <attribute qualifier="logFiles" type="LogFileCollection">
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" optional="true"
                dontOptimize="true" partof="true" />
            <persistence type="jalo" />
            <description>A list of log files related to the current CronJob</description>
        </attribute>

        //.....
    </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

**Logfile**

```
    <itemtype code="LogFile" extends="Media" jaloclass="de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.LogFile" autocreate="true"
              generate="true">

        <attributes>
            <attribute redeclare="true" qualifier="owner" type="CronJob">
                <modifiers read="true" write="false" initial="true" optional="false" private="false"/>
                <persistence type="cmp" qualifier="ownerPkString"/>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </itemtype>
```